# Dealing with spam by blocking URLs?

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

I run a giant community.
Many spammers will use link shorteners or .tk domains that 301 to their spam offer.
How are sites detecting the final domain and is this a viable solution to block spam?

ex. I'll just block the spam: bit.ly/xdfd but then they will just use a different shortened link.

Comment: Building off what @Baptiste said, you might mention what forum/CMS/etc you're using as there could be a feature or plugin of some kind that'll handle this for you.

Comment: it's a custom site. j0k gave me some good ideas, thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is plenty solutions to expand short url:

- [What is the best way in PHP or JS to expand shortened URLs like Bitly, Tinyurl to find the original URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495688/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-or-js-to-expand-shortened-urls-like-bitly-tinyurl-t)
- [ExpandUrl](https://github.com/romilb/ExpandUrl) (a java solution)
- [Expand short URL – Simple PHP app for beginners](http://blog.sanspace.in/expand-short-url/)
- [expanding short url to original url using PHP and CURL](http://hasin.me/2009/05/05/expanding-short-urls-to-original-urls-using-php-and-curl/)
- [Simple-URL-Expander](https://github.com/landeiro/Simple-URL-Expander) (a javascript solution)

When user submit a new post, you can apply a function that expand url for all url inside the post. Then you will have the real url. So you can appy what ever spam solution you use to reject / accept the post.

You can also replace the shorten url by the full one to avoid short link on your commutiy board.

Answer (score 1):

Many forums simply forbid all url shorteners. There is no simple solution to that, you may try also specific solutions for your platform (phpBB, vBulletin, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this a decided the best solution was to simply ban all shortened links, it will be very rare that a user will want to post such, but spammers love them.

I used code based on the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557116/regex-php-code-to-check-if-a-url-is-a-short-url

Comment: The code in from [so] won't really help.  It is trivial to add a query string to shortened URLs and still have them work.  Then they can be used to spam your site, but won't get caught by your code.  Something like https://bit.ly/2NCge1I?a

Comment: A URL shortener is different than just a "short URL". For example `http://bk.com/faq` is a short url, but not a "url shortener". Conversely, `http://tinyurl.com/example` is a longer url from a legit url shortener. Whatever solution you use, it won't be accurate if it's based solely on length.